# How to resolve Error CS0535: "[ClassName] does not implement interface member [InterfaceMethodName]"? (Azure Pipeline Failure)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interface, azure-pipelines

Whenever I build the Azure pipeline for my application, I'm getting the title error for an interface/class I have for sending emails. I've looked at other solutions on SO and none match the problem I seem to have.

This is the error I'm receiving from the pipeline build:

```
Error CS0535: 'SendEmail' does not implement interface member 'IEmailSender.SendEmailAsync(Message)
```

SendEmail.cs

```
public class SendEmail : IEmailSender
    {
        private readonly IOptions<EmailMessage> _mailSettings;
        public SendEmail(IOptions<EmailMessage> mailSettings)
        {
            _mailSettings = mailSettings;
        }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string body)
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient {
                Port = (int)_mailSettings.Value?.Port,
                Host = _mailSettings.Value?.Host,
                EnableSsl = _mailSettings.Value.UseSSL,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            };

            return client.SendMailAsync(_mailSettings.Value?.From, email, subject, body);
        }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(MailMessage message, string subject, string body)
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient {
                Port = (int)_mailSettings.Value?.Port,
                Host = _mailSettings.Value?.Host,
                EnableSsl = _mailSettings.Value.UseSSL,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            };

            message.From = new MailAddress(_mailSettings.Value.From);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;

            return client.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
    }
```

IEmailSender.cs

```
 public interface IEmailSender
    {
        Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string body);
        Task SendEmailAsync(MailMessage message, string subject, string body);
    }
```

The interface's method signatures and class method signatures match, so I'm at a loss as to why this error is occurring. I would also like to note I'm not using the IEmailSender interface that ASP.NET Core Identity uses. I'm able to send emails just fine and I don't receive any errors in the console. It wouldn't fail because my interface methods have the same name since they have didn't parameters, correct? Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The namespace for yourIEmailSender has to be same as where it is being called.  You may need to include the namespace so code can find the interface.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry I didn't include that part, but the two files are in the same folder, so the class can find the correct interface file. Like I said, everything works as it should, I'm just getting this weird error.

Comment: A namespace is like System.Net.Sockets.  You can have two sections of cs code in same folder but using different namespaces.  Check the namespaces in the project to make sure they are in the same namespace.  You can always add the full namespace of the code instead of defaulting and using the default namespace.

Comment: @jdweng You're right. They are however, both using the same namespace.

Comment: Are you missing "partial" to indicate the same class is in more than one module? Sometime it is useful to right click on a variable and select "Go To Definition" to make sure you do not have two definitions of the same variable.

Comment: @jdweng I checked for that already before posting. I searched in the Solution Explorer too and it is only in the one place.

Comment: You have two different overloads.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces?force_isolation=true#1763-uniqueness-of-implemented-interfaces

Comment: @jdweng So it looks like a naming issue then? Cause both interface methods are named the same?

Comment: There are more than one way of solving issue. Changing names or correcting the overload conditions will fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today:
I added a new method in the class that is located in (myCore.project) the interface was implemented in 3 other projects but I didn't know it. So I only implemented the method in the current project I was in and everything worked fine until the pipeline build throw error.

Solved:
I searched the interface in the entire solutand and looked all where the interface was used and I found 2 projects were using the interface. So I implemented the methods in those projects too.

I hope this might be helpful.